# What is the difference between 跟, 跟着 and 跟着着?

Tags: grammar, meaning, vocabulary

What is the difference between 跟着 and 跟? All dictionaries say that both can mean the verb "to follow".

If I want to use the 着 as a "particle indicating the continuation of an action or a state", should I use it once (跟着) or twice (跟着着)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than serving as a particle indicating the continuation of an action or a state, 着 also serves an important function.

Both 跟 and 跟着 are verbs that mean "follow", however, 跟 also has the additional meaning of "and, with, to go with", which will cause ambiguity in a sentence. For example,

- "她**跟**我" - does it mean "She **and** I or "She **follows** me"? However, the ambiguity/confusion is eliminated by adding the particle "着" - "她**跟着**我" (She **follows** me).

The expression "跟着着" is grammatically incorrect because the second "着" serves no function (which has been adequately taken care of by the particle immediately after the verb 跟).

Comment: Depending on context, the second 着 in 跟着着 may be pronounced as *zháo* or *zhuó* and becomes part of the next word, where it makes sense.